# After inserting a new record how to get the primary key

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am using webmatrix to design a simple form. My form also uses jquery ui a lot. In one of my modal windows I insert a new record. My table which is in Mysql has primary key in auto increment. 
After posting the new record, I used this code below if it was successful:

```
$.getJSON('shared/Partials/NewUser/' + $("#add-opno").val(), function (data) {
                        var newrecip = data;
                        console.log(newrecip.ID);

                    });
```

When I debugged my script noticed the console value is undefined. 
Below is the NewUser script.

```
@{
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
if(UrlData[0].IsInt()){
    var db = Database.Open("sb_cpd");
    var sql = "SELECT ID FROM cpd_recipients WHERE OpNo ='@0'";
    var recipient = db.QuerySingle(sql,UrlData[0]);
    Json.Write(recipient, Response.Output);
 }
}
```

Comment: So `recepient` is `null` ?

Comment: Its not null, but console log says : Cannot read property 'ID' of null . The ID is my primary key. Not null because when when I check in my database the values are insert. I understand I can use something like ExecuteScalar and Select Scope. How do I use this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you're saying 'Below is the NewUser script' however I see only a single select (not an insert) ? What am I missing ?

Comment: The script for insert is fine. The value is inserted in the table, nut I need to get the primary key which is auto increment from the table and use it in my form.

Comment: Check my edit, I've included a select to get you the last ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If I understood you correct, the way to get the last inserted ID in MySql DB (the equivalent of SCOPE_IDENTITY() in Sql Server goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table(Column1, Column2)
VALUES (@Column1, @Column1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Of course your table needs to have an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Otherwise you can get the highest value in the ID column like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cpd_recipients;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you please show me how to use Execute(query, parameters) with the SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(). I tested SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() on my table and it seems to work but dont know how to use it in my code.